# Как сделать чтобы фоновое видео работало на мобильных платформах?

Tags: javascript, html, css, видео

Как сделать чтобы видео фон отображался на мобильных платформах (iOS, Android)?

В настоящий момент фоновое видео работает в браузере, но не на мобильных устройствах (на смартфонах просто не езапускается, черный экран):

HTML:

```
<div class="video-container">
  <video autoplay loop muted id="video-bg">
    <source src="video/myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#video-bg {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  background-size: cover;
}
video {
  display: block;
}
.video-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

Встречал упоминания о каких-то хаках: но не нахожу работающих примеров.
Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я делал и на андроиде и айфоне так:

```html
<video playsinline loop autoplay="autoplay" muted preload="auto" id="video-bg">
  <source src="video/myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: Так вроде у меня так же? Контейнер снаружи для позиционирвоания. Проблема в том что видео не запускается на смартфонах.

Comment: Я добавлял src и в тег video + добавлял атрибут  playsinline=""

Comment: @Rumata, суть в том, что пропущены нужные атрибуты: `playsinline` - требуется для запуска видео на iOS, а может и уже в других местах, а так же браузеры давно запрещают "без согласия пользователя" запускать видео при загрузке страницы, но можно с установленным атрибутом `muted`.